# Update elasticsearch from 5.6.8 to 6.2.3

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update elasticsearch from 5.6.8 to 6.2.3 but i receive the error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/viamedici/infinitygate/elasticSearch/ElasticSearchClient.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Shared.

This is what i added my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
          <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
          <version>6.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my configuration client looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Client client()  {
    boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(transportSniff);
    String host = clusterNodes.split(":")[0];
    Integer port = Integer.parseInt(clusterNodes.split(":")[1]);
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.sniff", b)
            .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
            .build();
    TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
    try {
        transportClient.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        ErrorHandlingController.logger.error("Host/port problem", e);
    }
    INSTANCE = (Client) transportClient;
    return transportClient;
}
```

}

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

please remove:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and add in application.properties

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
```

Also please remove the trasport client bean definition

```
@Bean Client client() {
```

It will try to create a connection and will fail. If you are using docker to start elasticsearch, you can check this repository.
https://github.com/adinafometescu/tutorials/tree/master/spring-elasticsearch

I had the same problem as you described (during version migrations) and now everythinh works fine.